# WSO2 ESB is not listening REST API ports

Tags: connection-refused, wso2-esb

I'm on wso2 tutorial, at the en of this point https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message#SendingaSimpleMessage-uriTemplate
I've got web-interface of ESB running at localhost:9443/carbon
I've created and packed carbon application as it is described at "Sending a simple message" doc.
"APIs" page sais that I've got an API resource at   http://localhost:8280/healthcare
Sooo I'm trying to curl it and it fails:

```
[bajal@bajal:~/ESBTOOL/eclipse]# curl "http://localhost:8280/healthcare/querydoctor/surgery"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8280: Connection refused
```

netstat shows me that java-app (esb itself) has no open ports that could look like 8280.

I'm confused. There is nothing about it at ESB doc.
Please help me pass tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB uses Passthrough Listener to listen HTTP traffic on port 8280. This configuration lies on axis2.xml file inside your ESB. I can't remember the exact location now since now I am not into WSO2 much. There you have transport listener and sender configurations. I think it should be fine. Could you please change your curl request as follows [1] and try that out again. Alternatively hit the get url [2] in your browser's address bar and see.

[1] curl -v http://localhost:8280/healthcare/querydoctor/surgery

[2] http://localhost:8280/healthcare/querydoctor/surgery